# Istio Request Time out configurations for https/tls calls

Tags: istio

We are looking to leverage existing Istio functionality to configure request time-outs. Our Microservice is in the service mesh, and it makes a https call to external system. Is it possible to configure the timeouts for https calls?

We found this documentation of Istio , but the examples here are only HTTP :
[Istio Request Timeouts](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-timeouts/)

Answer (score 2):

Well when you use HTTPS/TLS, traffic is encrypted outside of Istio and therefore much Istio functionality is not available.

You could define a Service Entry and use TLS origination to let Istio do the upgrade, then you could also use a request timeout. See [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/).